# why pandas str.replace with .* pattern insers replacement value multiple times

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I am trying to use pandas `str.replace` function to replace a pattern.

But when i do:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text_col':['aaa', 'c', 'bbbbb', 'ddd']})['text_col'].str.replace('.*', 'RR')
```

it for some reason returns:

```
0    RRRR
1    RRRR
2    RRRR
3    RRRR
Name: text_col, dtype: object
```

While i would have though it should return the same as:

```
pd.DataFrame({'text_col':['aaa', 'c', 'bbbbb', 'ddd']})['text_col'].str.replace('^.*$', 'RR')
```

which returns:

```
0    RR
1    RR
2    RR
3    RR
Name: text_col, dtype: object
```

If i compare this behavior to R programming language, replacing the pattern `.*` and `^.*$` yields the same result. Why is it different in Pandas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the regex patterns are different.

- `a*` -> Zero or more of a.

Take a look at this example.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('.*', 'c')
# ['c', '']

>>> re.findall('.*', 'AAAAAAA')
# ['AAAAAAA', '']

>>> re.findall('.*', '')
# ['']
```

- `'.*'` matches empty strings too. `_.str.replace` replaces every match, so you always get two match i.e. one the actual string, two an empty string. So, you always get `'RRRR'`.

If you want to match one or match character you can use the below regex.

```
pat = r'.{1, }'
```

Comment: oh wow, didn't occur to me that it would be also matching empty string in a nonempty string. I though that the .* would just match the entire string.